# Error when reinstalling apache2

Tags: debian, apt, apache-2.4

I did an dist-upgrade on Debian Wheezy yesterday and got an error with syslog-nc-core.
I found that i should try to reinstall it and tried but it ended with an error that apache2 isnt configured.
I purged it also and when i now try to reinstall i get the error

```
Setting up apache2 (2.4.10-1) ...
Directory /etc/apache2/conf.d is not empty - leaving as is
Please note, that directory is considered obsolete and not read anymore by default
zz010_psa_httpd.conf
ERROR: Config file dir.conf not properly enabled: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf is a real file, not touching it
dpkg: error processing package apache2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any apache2 configuration that you need, the easiest way to resolve this is going to be to remove it all and let apt-get install a new default configuration for you.  Run:

```
apt-get purge apache2
rm -rf /etc/apache2
apt-get install apache2
```

You say you purged apache2, so maybe you already ran the first step, but apparently there were other custom files still left in /etc/apache2.  The second step will get rid of those.

Once you have a new default apache2 configuration, you can start to customize it.

If you need some of the configuration that's in /etc/apache2 now, probably your best bet is to back it up somewhere else first, wipe it clean and start fresh as above, then reimport the parts you need.

Note that in apache 2.4 in Debian, the old conf.d directory in /etc/apache2 has been replaced by conf-available and conf-enabled directories, similar to mods- and sites-.  You manage them with a2enconf/a2disconf, the same as a2enmod/a2dismod and a2ensite/a2dissite.